# Fibonacci in linear time by using an extra pointer

Tags: recursion, swift, fibonacci-sequence

I have a function to find the nth number in a Fibonacci sequence, in which I am recursively calling the function. The sum is stored in a class variable and I have an extra pointer I increment every time the function gets called.

This extra pointer is the gate keeper which dictates the base case of when to exit from the loop. The performance I get, using this algorithm is, \$O(n)\$ linear time and with \$O(1)\$space.

I get the expected answer but I am confused if this an acceptable solution from a coding interview stand point.

```
var x = 0
var sum = 0
func myFibonacci(of n: Int, a: Int, b:Int) -> Int {
  x+=1
  if (x == n) {
    return sum
  } else {
    sum = a+b
    return myFibonacci(of: n, a: b, b: sum)
  }
}

let finalAns = myFibonacci(of: 9, a: 0, b: 1)
print("The nth number in Fibonacci sequence is \(finalAns)")
```

Output: 34

Time complexity: \$O(n)\$ linear time

Space complexity \$O(1)\$

Is this an acceptable solution for a coding interview?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your function uses *global variables,* which is bad for several reasons:

- The variables must be reset before the function can be called again.
- The variables can be modified from outside of your function, causing
  wrong results.
- The function is not thread-safe.

In addition,

- The program logic is not immediately obvious (at least it wasn't to me).
- Calling the function with `n <= 0` causes an integer overflow.

Global variables are often problematic, and
here they can be easily avoided, making the code not only safer,
but also simpler.

First, the global `sum` variable is elimitated by making
it local:

```
var x = 0
func myFibonacci(of n: Int, a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    x += 1
    if (x == n) {
        return b
    } else {
        let sum = a + b
        return myFibonacci(of: n, a: b, b: sum)
    }
}
```

or eliminate it completely:

```
var x = 0
func myFibonacci(of n: Int, a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    x += 1
    if (x == n) {
        return b
    } else {
        return myFibonacci(of: n, a: b, b: a + b)
    }
}
```

Now get rid of the global variable `x` by decrementing `n` instead
in the recursive call:

```
func myFibonacci(of n: Int, a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    if n == 1 { 
        return b // Recursion terminates here
    }
    return myFibonacci(of: n - 1, a: b, b: a + b)
}
```

With a slight modification it works for `n = 0` as well.
Negative arguments should be caught instead of recursing 
repeatedly until an integer overflow occurs:

```
func myFibonacci(of n: Int, a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    precondition(n >= 0, "`n` must be non-negative")
    if n == 0 {
        return a // Recursion terminates here
    }
    return myFibonacci(of: n - 1, a: b, b: a + b)
}
```

This is what I would expect as a recursive implementation in a coding interview (of course you can also implement it iteratively,
or use a [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) such as Binet's formula).

As a bonus, you can implement it for negative arguments as well,
compare [Generalizations of Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers):

```
func myFibonacci(of n: Int, a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    if n == 0 {
        return a // Recursion terminates here
    } else if n > 0 {
        return myFibonacci(of: n - 1, a: b, b: a + b)
    } else {
        return myFibonacci(of: n + 1, a: b - a, b: a)
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed your style is much cleaner and safer. Thanks